# `be + verb + ing` with `be`. I can easily understand as only 'be' is being 'am,is,are,were,was' but I've been confusing about with "be" itself

Tags: present-continuous

> We are pleased to be opening this facility in your town. We will be bringing roughly 100 new jobs **<strike>in</strike> to** Colton.

What I've been confused is about `be + verb + ing` .

How should I interpret it?

About the sentences which I've written above, I interpreted it as following.

> We are ready and happy to open this facility in your town. We will bring roughly 100 new jobs to Colton.

About `be + verb + ing`, I can easily understand like following phrases.

> He is washing dishes. I am working on my school assignments. They are watching us.

I think this is the first time when I seriously trying to understand the meaning of `be + verb + ing` with "be" itself.

Which article(s) is/are recommended to let me understand it? Or can you explain about it here?

Comment: You need to review these tenses in English; present continuous (also known as present progressive) versus present simple. But your first sentence uses another tense: the future continuous: will be bringing.

Comment: In your first cited context it's really just a stylistic choice to use continuous (as opposed to *We will **bring** 100 new jobs...*). Arguably the continuous form adds "immediacy" (*It's going to be / will be happening* more strongly links the future to the present than *It will happen*). But things are different with *He is washing dishes*, which explicitly means that's what he's doing *right now*, whereas *He washes dishes* means that's something he *habitually* does, even if he's not actually doing it at time of speaking.